# Should Google OAuth2 .json files be transferred?

Tags: python, json, oauth, google-api

I've written a Python script, using Google's OAuth2 framework, for downloading files from Google Drive. To use OAuth2, I had to register the "app" with Google, which then gave me two `.json` files, `client_id.json` and `client_secret.json`.

I've successfully run the script from a friend's computer, but I have to include those two `.json` files in the directory when first running it. The script logs on to that account's Google Drive (i.e., not mine) and downloads files from there, all without a problem, so it works.

My question is: am I supposed to transfer the `.json` files to someone else if I give them the script to run? One of the files is called `client_secret.json`, so it doesn't seem like it's supposed to work that way, but I don't see any other way of doing it.

Comment: Are you using a client side (installed applications/browser-javascript) Oauth workflow or server side? I am certain *to some extent* that client side workflow should not require client secret. For a server side workflow, the server manages storing of client_secret.

Comment: Not 100% sure, to be honest. I'm new to this. I just wrote a Python script and ran it. :) Are you saying that maybe all I need to give the other person is the `client_id.json` file?

Comment: Are you actually using the client secret json file? If yes, you are probably using the server side workflow. In that case you should NOT distribute your application. You should put it in a server and expose web services. If you are distributing it, you should use a client side workflow -- it doesn't need client_secret.json file.